# Einstein analytics. Update the template?

Tags: einstein-analytics

what steps i need to follow to add second dashboard in a template?
How to make changes in template-info.json to add dataflow/dataset ?

Comment: Which platform you are talking about? What have you done so far? Try to give us more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can add only one dataflow in the template. This is the salesforce limitation. So use only one dataflow to create multiple dashboards. Try to include related objects 
in a dataflow if you want to show that objects data on a dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would need to update your template-info.json file to add new dashboard, lesne, dataset, data flow etc:

Each has their sections - if not present create one:

> ```
> "dashboards":[{file, name , condition}]
> "lenses":[{file,name}]
> "datasetFiles":[{name,label,userXMD}]
> "eltDataflows": [{name,file}]
> ```

in above, files path needs to be given like dataflow/df1.json etc.

Comment: Through trailhead org for analytics  we can add only one dataflow in a template.Is it correct ? & if we going to add second dataflow & dashboard related to the second dataflow it gives error. Can you please provide example ?

Comment: Yes, I have not tried to add second dataflow yet and it does not seem to be possible either for now. Check if you can modify same dataflow.

Comment: Only one eltdataflow is supported message, while deploying through eclipse. Is it org limit ? Can we add the second dataflow to the first dataflow ? If you have any suggestion, please provide me.